# Preventing direct access to robots.txt through .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I want to prevent users from accessing my robots.txt file but I still want search engines to read it. Is it possible?
If yes then how do I do it? I believe if I write following in .htaccess it will work but I am afraid it will also block search engines from accessing it.

> order deny, allow
>   deny from all

Thanks

Comment: There is an answer you could adapt to your case on "robots.txt": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475870/robots-txt-htaccess-block-google?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since standard `robots.txt` is served from the root of your domain unless you can somehow reliably distinguish search engines from users I don't think what you are asking is possible.

You could try filtering by user agent or possibly by IP range.

Is there a reason why you don't want your users to not see what is in your robots.txt file? After all everything in that file is public.

Comment: Yeah I also figured it out that it is not possible otherwise Google, CNN, BBC and others would have also prevented their robots.txt (google.com/robots.txt, bbc.com/robots.txt). I just got a query from someone so I thought to ask ask and confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use x-robots-tag or robots meta tags instead of robots.txt to reduce your reliance on the file. For example add the following directive to your .htaccess file.

```html
<Files ~ "\pdf$">
     #don't index pdf files
     Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</Files>
```