# robots.txt htaccess block google

Tags: .htaccess, search-engine, robots.txt

In my .htaccess file I have:

```
<Files ~ "\.(tpl|txt)$">
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

This denies any text file from being read, but the Google search engine gives me the following error:

```
robots.txt Status

http://mysite/robots.txt

18 minutes ago  302 (Moved temporarily)
```

How can I modify .htaccess to permit Google to read robots.txt while prohibiting everyone else from accessing text files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
<Files ~ "\.(tpl|txt)$">
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "Googlebot" goodbot
  Allow from env=goodbot
</Files>
```